# Adding date picker dynamically using jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a web page in which I have a date-picker. The date-picker works perfectly well when I put it directly in my HTML code. It works by just clicking on the input box. However, when I try to add the same element (after removing it from HTML) dynamically using jquery it doesn't pop up the calendar when I click on it.

This is the HTML and javascript codes:

```js
$("#deliv_info").append(
  '<a>Delivery Date:</a><br>' +
  '<input class="input_box" id="inputField_2" /><br><br>'
  );
```

```html
<!--  This works fine
<a>Delivery Date:</a><br>
<input class="input_box" id="inputField_2" /><br><br>
-->

<!-- This one does not work  -->
<div id="deliv_info">
</div>
```

Here, it is working without adding it with jquery:

[image]

Comment: I can't see anything here which would cause a datepicker to appear. Where's the code which assigns the datepicker to the textbox?

Comment: Try it the other way : `blablabla.appendTo("#deliv_info")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var input = $("<input/>", {
                class: 'input_box',
            })
$(input).datepicker();

$("#deliv_info").append(input);
```

I've made a fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/dsnL08d9/1/)

Comment: All thanks to you SiMag. Now, it is working perfectly for me. Although, I had to get rid of that date-picker totally and used jquery-ui date-picker. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your datepicker like this,

```
$('#deliv_info').on('focus',"#inputField_2", function(){
    $(this).datepicker(); 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$(document).on('focus',"#inputField_2", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

The conventional method does'nt works for dynamic html textbox, but this one is tested and works fine.

Comment: Thanks Pandeyz for help :)

Comment: But the problem is, I don't have such a function "datepicker" for creating date-picker elements. All I have to do is, putting an input element and specifying the class as "input_box" and id as "inputField_2" specifically. I found this date-picker codes from the internet, that's why. So what do I do please?